# Hammer.js Pinch-to-zoom not working

Tags: image, hammer.js

**UPDATE:** Got a jsfiddle up @ http://jsfiddle.net/gacDy/7/ , however, I can't even seem to get this working correctly. I'll keep working on it, but hopefully it'll help.

I'm using `Hammer.js` for an app I'm working on. For now, I've got a demo that I got on the web somewhere that I'm using to figure out how to make this work. For the demo I have two images (I'll post screenshots below) that I'm trying to get to zoom independently with `hammer.js`.

As things are right now, both images zoom, but the second one zooms into the region where the first image is. (See screenshots below)

Pre-zoom image:

[image]

Post-zoom image:

[image]

Code for images:

```
<div id="zoom2">
<img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="377" />
</div>
<div id="zoom">
<img src="waldo.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="377" />
</div>
```

Functions and such:

```
<div id="debug"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hammer.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.specialevent.hammer.js"></script>
<script>

var debug_el = $("#debug");

// disable the dragging of images on desktop browsers
$("img").bind("dragstart", function() {
    return false;
});


$(function(){
    var zoom = new ZoomView('#zoom','#zoom :first');
});


function ZoomView(container, element) {

    container = $(container).hammer({
        prevent_default: true,
        scale_treshold: 0,
        drag_min_distance: 0
    });

    element = $(element);


    // prefixes
    var vendorPrefixes = ["", "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-o-", "-ms-", "-khtml-"];

    var displayWidth = container.width();
    var displayHeight = container.height();

    //These two constants specify the minimum and maximum zoom
    var MIN_ZOOM = 1;
    var MAX_ZOOM = 5;

    var scaleFactor = 1;
    var previousScaleFactor = 1;

    //These two variables keep track of the X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first
    //touches the screen
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;

    //These two variables keep track of the amount we need to translate the canvas along the X
    //and the Y coordinate
    var translateX = 0;
    var translateY = 0;

    //These two variables keep track of the amount we translated the X and Y coordinates, the last time we
    //panned.
    var previousTranslateX = 0;
    var previousTranslateY = 0;

    //Translate Origin variables

    var tch1 = 0, 
        tch2 = 0, 
        tcX = 0, 
        tcY = 0,
        toX = 0,
        toY = 0,
        cssOrigin;

    var last_drag_event;

    container.bind("transformstart", function(event){
        //We save the initial midpoint of the first two touches to say where our transform origin is.
        tch1 = [event.touches[0].x, event.touches[0].y];
        tch2 = [event.touches[1].x, event.touches[1].y];

        tcX = (tch1[0]+tch2[0])/2;
        tcY = (tch1[1]+tch2[1])/2;

        toX = tcX;
        toY = tcY;

        cssOrigin = toX +"px "+ toY +"px";
    });

    container.bind("transform", function(event) {
        scaleFactor = previousScaleFactor * event.scale;
        scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

        transform(event);
    });

    container.bind("transformend", function(event) {
        previousScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    });

    container.bind("drag", function(event) {
        cssOrigin = (toX + (toX-event.position.x) / scaleFactor) +"px " +
                    (toY + (toY-event.position.y) / scaleFactor) +"px";

        transform(event);
        last_drag_event = event;
    });

    container.bind("dragend", function(event) {
        toX += ((toX - last_drag_event.position.x) / scaleFactor);
        toY += ((toY - last_drag_event.position.y) / scaleFactor);


        cssOrigin = toX +"px "+ toY +"px";
        transform(event);

        debug_el.text('TX: '+toX+' TY: '+toY);
    });


    function transform(event) {
        //We're going to scale the X and Y coordinates by the same amount
        var cssScale = "scale("+ scaleFactor +")";

        var props = {};
        $(vendorPrefixes).each(function(i, vendor) {
            props[vendor +"transform"] = cssScale;
            props[vendor +"transform-origin"] = cssOrigin;
        });
        element.css(props);


        debug_el.text('TX: '+translateX+' TY: '+translateY+' '+element.css('-webkit-transform-origin'))
    }

}
</script>
```

-- I duplicated the above code and changed any references to the first image to reference the second image in order to make the second image zoomable. But like I mentioned it's not working correctly. I've tried changing around all my variable names in case I missed a reference to the 1st image that could be causing this overlap but nothing has helped.

**EDIT:** This may also be pertinent:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<style>
    #zoom {
        height: 377px;
        width: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
        background: #eee;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
    }
</style>
<meta name="viewport2" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<style>
    #zoom2 {
        height: 377px;
        width: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:static;
        background: #eee;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

I just need help figuring out how to keep the second image from disappearing into the 1st image when zooming. I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks all.

Comment: Would you set this up in a jsfiddle? Would help nudge someone to clone the fiddle, dive in, and debug your issue--hopefully generating a solve which would greatly help a bunch of developers using hammer.js.

Comment: I'll set one up right now

Comment: Just updated original post with link to jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/gacDy/5/

Comment: Still cant figure out what's wrong with my fiddle... anyone know if it could have something to do with the options available in the side bar? This is the first time I've set up a fiddle so I'm not sure about all of the settings

Comment: Problem solved! Bought license to Smooth Zoom Pan - jQuery Image Viewer @ <http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142> Very simple, totally worth the money. Might be important to mention: Single license was $10, but I'm pretty sure I was given a $10 credit for purchasing it. Not sure why exactly, was the first time I'd bought anything from codecanyon, though.